# Need Sample code for heap corruption in C++

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-c++, heap-corruption

I am trying to learn and understand debugging heap corruption in VC++.

I found nice artilce on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543097(v=vs.85).aspx).

Can someone provide me a sample code to reproduce the heap corruption issue.
so that i can follow the steps mentioned in msdn article and get the some hands on.

Comment: try to free memory which is allocated in heap.

Comment: most people on stackoverflow don't need help creating heap corruption.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%5D+heap+corruption ;-)

Comment: You could try writing your own `string` class, that usually does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to corrupt heap:

```
char *cp = new char[10];
(*(cp - 5))++;
```

That should corrupt the header in front of the allocated memory block. It should also give you an idea on hiw to create specific kinds of corrupted header data, if you look up the structure of the header created by your compiler.

You might want to experiment with optimizations disabled, as this is undefined behavior, and optimizer might do some funny things with UB code. When in doubt, examine the assembly output of compiler or machine code disassembly in debugger to see what code got generated.